# Is there a pure-CSS solution to size a sibling of a floated element to the full remaining height in its parent (no absolute positioning)?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, css-float

I've got a div containing some text that's the sibling of a "float:right" element.  As the parent div is resized horizontally, the floated element may or may not be above the div containing the text.  Is there a pure-CSS solution (i.e. no JavaScript), to have the div containing the text expand to occupy the remaining height in its parent?

So, if the floated element isn't above the div containing the text, it should occupy the full height of the parent.  Otherwise, it should occupy all of the height below it, but it should not overflow outside the parent.

I admit the English description may be hard to visualize, so I've written some code in HTML to illustrate.  In the sample, the top widget stack represents the behavior I'm looking for, but is achieved via JavaScript.  The bottom stack is the default behavior with just the CSS I could come up with.

- Open the HTML in a browser (tested in Chrome) and resize the browser window horizontally to see the difference in behavior of the top and bottom stacks.  Note that this sample has been simplified, so please don't offer a solution that depends on the parent div being at or almost at the top level.
- Observe that in the bottom stack, the blue div is pushed down and overflows the rect of the parent div when the floated element is forced on top of it by resizing the window.  I want to achieve the behavior of the top stack, where the blue div is resized shorter when the floated element moves over it, but with pure CSS.

Is this possible?  What CSS should be applied?  No JQuery, please, or approaches using absolute positioning.

```js
    /* Set the inner DIV to maximum height without overflowing outer DIV */
    function hackit () {
        var elm = document.getElementById("goodtext");
        elm.style.height="calc(100% - " + elm.offsetTop + "px)"
    };
    
    window.addEventListener("load", hackit);
    window.addEventListener("resize", hackit);
```

```html
    <!-- Outer DIV -->
    <DIV style="position:absolute;left:25%;WIDTH:75%;HEIGHT:150px;
                background-color:yellow;overflow:hidden;">
    
    <!-- Controls DIV - floated -->
    <DIV style="float:right;width:50%;height:20px;line-height:20px;
                background-color:greenyellow;">
    CONTROLS
    </DIV>
    
    <!-- Inner text DIV -->
    <DIV ID="goodtext" 
         style="display:inline-block;width:200px;height:100%;
                writing-mode:tb-rl;background-color:cyan;">
    One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen
    fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen twenty
    </DIV>
    </DIV>
    
    <!-- Outer DIV -->
    <DIV style="position:absolute;left:25%;TOP:250px;WIDTH:75%;HEIGHT:150px;
                background-color:orange;overflow:hidden;">
    
    <!-- Controls DIV - floated -->
    <DIV style="float:right;width:50%;height:20px;line-height:20px;
                background-color:greenyellow;">
    CONTROLS
    </DIV>
    
    <!-- Inner text DIV -->
    <DIV style="display:inline-block;width:200px;height:100%;
                writing-mode:tb-rl;background-color:cyan;">
    One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen
    fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen twenty
    </DIV>
    </DIV>
```

Comment: Would you please edit your question and clarify it. You don't have any "textbox"es in your code. Perhaps refer to the blocks by their color.

Comment: It may sound a bit more awkward now, but I've reworded it.